GitHub Actions returns Unexpected symbol: '"foo"' on my simple conditional statement
When when I execute this job,
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      bar: foo
    steps:
      - name: Conditional Test
        if: env.foo == "foo"

I get this response,

The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/build-plugin.yml (Line: 18, Col: 13): Unexpected symbol: '"foo"'. Located at position 12 within expression: env.foo == "foo"


The problem is because you used double quotes. In conditionals, you have to use single quotes. Not
if: env.foo == "foo"

But,
if: env.foo == 'foo'

Then you should see this in DEBUG,
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Conditional Test'
##[debug]Evaluating: (success() && (env.foo == 'foo'))
##[debug]Evaluating And:
##[debug]..Evaluating success:
##[debug]..=> true
##[debug]..Evaluating Equal:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating env:
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'foo'
##[debug]....=> null
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'foo'
##[debug]..=> false
##[debug]=> false
##[debug]Expanded: (true && (null == 'foo'))
##[debug]Result: false

